# I yelled at and around my cat and now he doesn't trust me as much and doesnt like to snuggle anymore what can i do to help him

Tags: cats, behavior

Long story short, I got help, am on meds now, and doing better. I had screaming matches with my neighbors and even yelled at myself as dumb as it sounds and a few times at my cat [2 years old].

He now doesn't trust me as much. He used to fall asleep on my lap, now he's starting to pull fur out, given there is a new kitten around [I figured he could use a friend for when I start working again].

I'd really like to rebuild our friendship because I'm not that person anymore, I'd really appreciate any help on this. I love this cat with all my heart and hate myself for what I did, so please help me figure out how to rebuild what we had. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Have a look into this search, there are multiple similar questions already answered here: https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=trust+cat

Comment: it sounds to me like you are taking responsability for your own health so the next step is to build trust in yourself,your cat will build trust over time as long as nothing bad happens.